# How to use associations with activerecord-tableless gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, activemodel

I am trying to go table-less with [activerecord-tableless](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-tableless/versions/1.3.4). The main reason to use it is for the associations. [Here](https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless)(in the github documentation) it tells you how to simply work with one model but doesn't say anything about associations. 
For example: I have a User and Category model. Each User belongs to a Category. 
This is my User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_no_table
  belongs_to :category

  column :id, :integer
  column :name, :string
  column :email, :string
  column :password, :string
  column :created_at, :string
  column :updated_at, :string
  column :category_id, :integer

  validates :name, :email, :password, presence: true
  validates_length_of :password, minimum: 8
end
```

Now, in the form, I have to get all the categories to select from like this

```
 <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :title) %>
```

From where, `Category.all` can retrieve its content. Do I have to override it?
Also, suppose I have a User object and I need to find it's Category object(if I have a category id), then will '`find`' work?

If everything has to be overridden, then what is the use of [activerecord-tableless.](https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless)

I am not able to find any documentation or tutorials regarding this. Please help.

PS: I have tried ActiveModel as well but they do not support associations.

PPS: Rails 4.1.1 and Ruby 1.9.3 is being used.